# How to stop the chef client which is running at regular intervals?

Tags: chef-infra

I just execute this command 'chef-client -i 30' in my one of the node. So the chef client runs every 30 seconds. Now I need to stop this chef-client run. How to stop the chef-client? Meanwhile this command start the chef client run with 30 seconds waits first. But I need to run the chef-client first and then wait 30 seconds and again run simultaneously. How this command executes

```
           _____       _____
     30sec| run |30sec| run |
     wait |     | wait|     |       -->30 sec wait and run & wait,...
    ______|     |_____|     |_____






     _____       _____ 
    | 1st |30sec| run |30sec
    | run | wait|     |wait       -->1st run and wait and run,...
    |     |_____|     |_____
```

Initially, It dont need to wait for 30 seconds. Am I thought anything wrong?
thanks...

Comment: I don't even understand what is the problem...

Comment: @Tensibai How to stop the chef-client run command.It will run for every 30 seconds.n How to stop that? Is any command is there like 'chef-client stop'

Comment: Just kill the process with task manager or kill (windows or Linux)

Comment: Is that only way @Tensibai

Comment: There is `chef-client --once`. which runs chef and stops the service.

Comment: @VijayVishnu Well, if you launch something to run in a loop, you'll have to break the loop. Sounds like your use case is not answered by the daemon mode of chef, make a bash script like: `chef-client; sleep 30; chef-client`

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep command to filter the running chef process,
**ps -ef |grep chef**

Then kill all the process to stop the chef-client.
**kill -9 process_id**

Otherwise you can see the file, **/var/chef-solo/cache/chef-client-running.pid to get the client pid**. Then by killing that you can stop it.